# How to make an app really full screen?

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I am using macOS Ventura 13.4 (22F66).

I am using Adobe Audition and I want to make it REALLY full screen.

I have the Dock hidden and also the menu bar.

I click on Audition's green button and there is no `Enter Full Screen` option there. This function is not also present on the View menu.

After double tapping the app's title bar, the app goes semi-full screen.

I am stuck with this ugly gray bar at the top.

[image]

Is there a way of removing it?

Comment: Adobe apps just don't behave like 'real' Mac apps. In Photoshop there's a way to toggle screen modes from the menu - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEeTW.png - or by pressing F, but Audition doesn't seem to have this, according to google. [Can't test, I only have Photoshop.]

Comment: I was suspecting that. Thanks.